# fragment, add fragment of fragmentTransaction,

Tags: android, android-fragments

The problem scenario: I have three fragments: FragA, FragB, FragC. There is a base activity which contains these three fragments. So, now instead of replacing, I am adding the fragments using fragment transaction. The sequence is as follows: on moving from FragA to FragB to FragC and then coming back from FragC to FragB. 
    Now, my doubt is, on coming back from FragC to FragB, none of the methods from the lifecycle of FragB is called, I even verified it by debugging all the methods present in the lifecycle of FragB. On the contrary, when we use replace method of fragment transaction, onCreateView() of fragB gets called.

If there is any confusion in the understanding of question then kindly let me know and apologies if, a definition of the problem is not well framed.

Comment: Can you put some code how you are maintaining fragment transition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Replace**: This removes the existing fragment and adds a new fragment i.e it removes frag B and add frag C when you make a transaction.
Also when you press back button the frag B  that got replaced will be created with its onCreateView being invoked.

Fragment's life cycle events onPause, onResume, onCreateView will be invoked here.

**Add**:This retains the existing fragments and adds a new fragment i.e it wont remove frag B and add frag C when you make a transaction.
Here the previous fragment i.e frag B will be active and they wont be in 'paused' state so when a back button is pressed onCreateView is not called for the fragB.

Fragment's life cycle events onPause, onResume, onCreateView wont be invoked here.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your informative answer. But just one more doubt: Here the previous fragment i.e frag B will be active. What exactly does it mean? As when fragC is overlaid on fragB. So, apparently, frag B's onPause should be invoked. and on back navigation from C to B, B's onResume() should be invoked. right ?

Comment: Yes..frag B onPause is not called and it will be active..on pressing back the fragC will just pop and the previous fragB will be visible again and no methods are called in fragB.

Comment: For better and clear understanding I suggest you to create a sample app containing two fragments and try out all the options like add,replace,addTobackstack methods..It will make all your doubts clear.

Comment: okay, sure I will create a sample app and perform the implementations of add and replace methods. Thank you, for your answer

Answer (score 0):

If you **ADD** the fragment, when its coming back from Frag C to B, the page doesn't refresh. So the service which you place in the fragment B doesn't call again.
eg.placing a book one over another and make a rack.

If you **REPLACE** the fragment, the fragment in the stack gets override.

eg: place a book in a table.only one book is allowed to keep in the table. So everytime it should be replaced by another book.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.container, fragment,back_stack_name); //replace
transaction.addToBackStack(back_stack_name);//need to add in backstack or not. if not set as null
fragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener(this);
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: hi, your analogy to my problem definition was really explanatory. But, my doubt is: in Android terms, if any fragment is overlaid on the previous fragment then the previous fragment's onPause() is invoked. right? kindly correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

you can check fragments visibility.

override setMenuVisibility in your fragment:

```
  @Override
  public void setMenuVisibility(boolean menuVisible) {
      super.setMenuVisibility(menuVisible);
      if(menuVisible){
           //fragment is on top and visible
      }
      .....
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In terms of fragment's life cycle events onPause, onResume, onCreateView and other life cycle events will be invoked in case of **replace** but they won't be invoked in case of **add**.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using an Activity which use 3 Fragments whose purpose its to login and register, so every time want to add a Fragment and to get lifecycle of every Fragment you should replace the current one and so on. You could use the next method on onClick call and pass on argument the newInstance Fragment

```
private void setFragment(Fragment fr) {
    // create Fragment transaction
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    // Adding to back stack that will allow you use onBackPressed
    fTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    // Replacing fragment_container which will made lifecycle works 
    fTransaction.replace(R.id.initio, fr, fr.getTag());
    // Commit so inflates the new fragment
    fTransaction.commit();
}
```

Also if you want to get back between Fragments using onBackPressed you should override next method:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

    if (count == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();

    } else {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
}´
```

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Traditionally, I should have used replace method but accidentally I came across this scenario and it was a bit confusing as no method from the lifecycle of a fragment is been invoked. And so out of curiosity, I wanted to know the answer to this particular problem.